# Show that the following function is continuous on Q:

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $h : \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by 
$$
h(x)= \begin{cases}
0,
&\ x^2<2\\ \ \\ 1,&\ x^2>2
\end{cases}
$$

see why this function is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$, but I can't show it. Maybe we could work with the epsilon-delta criterion?

So for every $\epsilon> 0$ we find a $\delta> 0$  with $| x - x_0 | <\delta$ implying $ | h(x) - h(x_0) | < \epsilon$ ? Am I right? How do I have to choose my $\delta$ then?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt 2\notin \mathbb Q$.  Thus in a neighborhood of every rational the function is a constant.

Comment: Excuse me, my bad${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q\in \mathbb Q$.

Since  $q\ne\sqrt2$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sqrt2\not\in(q-\delta,q+\delta)$. So $h$ is constant on $(q-\delta,q+\delta)$, and thus
$$
|h(x)-h(q)|=0<\varepsilon
$$
for any $\varepsilon>0$ that you choose.

Comment: I see. Could I choose $\delta$ = | sqrt(2) - q | / 2 then? By the way: thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, indeed. $ $